# When is static data in function destroyed

Tags: c++, singleton, destructor

I'm learning how to implement the singleton with C++ and I've read this link: [C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern)

I have one question: Why is the "Meyers Singleton" guaranteed-destruction?

```
class S
{
    public:
        static S& getInstance()
        {
            static S    instance;
            return instance;
        }
    private:
        S() {}
        S(S const&);  
        void operator=(S const&);
 };
```

In my opinion, in this case, the time of destruction of the variable `instance` is out of control too. Meaning that it is destroyed after the main returns. If I'm right , why it can be regarded as `guaranteed-destruction`?

```
class S
{
    public:
        static S& getInstance()
        {
            return instance;
        }
        S() {}
    private:
        static S instance;
        S(S const&);  
        void operator=(S const&);
 };

 S S::instance = S();
```

Is this guaranteed-destruction too?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008050/1413395) specifically.

Comment: Objects with static lifetimes are destroyed after `main`returns, in reverse order of their construction.